# Sorting a list based on boolean and datetime values

Tags: python, list, sorting, datetime, dictionary

I have a list:

```
[{'added_on': datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 30, 13, 1, 40, 84539, tzinfo=<UTC>),
  'priority': False,
  'userEmail': u'xxx@yyy.com',
  'Id': 16123},...]
```

I need to get it sorted out such that the dicts with priority as True should top the list in reverse chronological order and the rest in reverse chronology as well.

Tried:

```
List = sorted(List, key=lambda item: item['priority'])
List = sorted(List, key=lambda item: item['added_on'])
```

Gets sorted on chronology.

How can this be implemented.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're to sort on multiple predicates, you'll need to have `sorted` work on tuples.

```
lst = sorted(List, key=lambda item: (not item['priority'], -item['added_on'].timestamp()) )
```

The second argument `item['added_on'].timestamp()` means converting the `datetime` object to its equivalent in epochs, and then reversing the sign so it is sorted in reverse on that predicate.

Comment: I think it should be "not item['priority']" instead of "item['priority']", since the sort functions seems to put False elements before the True ones (I guess it's because it converts it to digit and 0 < 1).